# ColdFusion 10 can cfdump the value of a struct's key, but can't assign that value to another variable?

Tags: struct, coldfusion

I have a struct numRes with keys through which I'm cflooping, (long story), and I can `<cfdump>` `#structFind(numRes,d)#` and see exactly what I want. I see that the key DOES exist and DOES have content, but if I try and do:

```
 <cfset args.q=structFind(numRes,d) />
```

I get an exception

> Cannot find [value of d that I did see in the dump] in the structure.

So the key DOES exist, in a dump, but doesn't exist the second I try and set it.  Why???  I swear this worked Friday...  However, this is NOT the first time I've been able to `<cfdump>` on a struct's key and see the value, while being unable to use the value contained therein.  I also confess to being a mostly-newbie to CF.

I've also tried:

```
    <cfscript>
        structInsert(args,"q",structFind(numRes,d));
    </cfscript>
```

Didn't really expect it to work, but figured I'd try.

(I need to assign something to `args.q` because I'm invoking a pile of code I don't control, passing it the args struct, and that pile's looking for a q key; otherwise I wouldn't be bothering with this.)

To address comments (and give some more info):
Precise CF version is ColdFusion 10,285437, running on Windows Server 2008, hitting a SQL Server 2012 database.

numRes.d is very much not null; cfdump would've said null if it was null, no?
numRes["#d#"] throws the error, "Element [d] is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression.  This might also be a good time to note that this is part of a CFC WSDL.

Since a stand-alone example was requested, I'm going to do my best without posting anything that'll get me in trouble with work...  I'm basically trying to write an app to find duplicate customers across one-to-four (at present) data sources, and d above is the DSN in subsequent queries, because based on results of that first invocation, I only want to hit the DSNs that returned results, not all four, so I set each DSN's result to be a structure key 1) to keep the results organized by DSN, and 2) so I could easily built a list or array from that for my later stuff.

numRes is a query object that's returned from that first , on another pile of code I can't modify.  (We call these piles "shared code" because we're a creative bunch.)  So it's created via the returnvariable="" part of the tag.

This is as best as I can do with self-contained yet minimalistic.  "Self-contained" is hard because I'm invoking all of this other stuff:

```
    <cfcomponent>
        <cffunction name="myDummyFunction" access="remote" httpMethod="get" hint="" output="true" returntype="string" returnformat="json">
            <!--- Stuff --->

            <cfinvoke component="#pileOfSharedCode#" method="getCustomer"  returnvariable="numRes">
                <cfinvokeargument name="dsn" value="#listOfDSNsToBeSearched#" />
             </cfinvoke>

             <cfif isDefined("numRes") AND isStruct(numRes)>
               <cfset dsnsToSearchBecauseTheyHadResults=structKeyArray(numRes) />
             <cfloop index="d" array="#DSNsToSearch#">
                  <cfset args.q=structFind(numRes,d) />

                  <cfinvoke method="methodIWantToInvokeOnOneDNSsResultsFromPreviousInvoke" returnvariable="thing">
                      <cfinvokeargument name="args" value="#args#" />
                 </cfinvoke>
            </cfloop>
         </cfif>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Can you post a [small, *stand-alone*, example](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the issue? Also, what version of CF are you running?

Comment: @Leigh I'd edited my question to specify CF 10.  Somehow that disappeared...  Example in a moment.

Comment: Is the value `Null`?

Comment: Okay. I am curious to see the runnable example.  As an aside, I rarely use `structInsert/Find`. My preference is using associative array notation for accessing or assigning key values ie `structName["keyName"]` and `structKeyExists` to test for a keys existence.

Comment: (Edit) I have not read the full update yet, but this statement jumped out at me: *numRes is a query object*  Was that a typo? Because a query object is not the same thing as a structure ...

Comment: @Leigh I may not have been sufficiently precise, each key holds a query object.  It may also show my usual languages that I would use object and structure interchangeably?

Comment: While I appreciate the challenge of trying to post a "santized" repro case, it is difficult to follow what is really going on without the actual values, object types, etc.. But it sounds like you are saying `numRes` is a structure. The "key" is the name of a datasource, and the "value" is a query object that was run against that datasource?

Comment: @Leigh The "value" is the result of a <cfquery>, yes.  And to post a full example would take an amount of work that would make it more worth my while to just re-write the pile of shared code, and I can't share any of that here, anyway.

Comment: No, not the whole thing, just the portion causing the problem: the cfif and cfloop. That part only requires a structure, which you says contains of four keys.  It should not take long to dummy up a structure and query object. FWIW, it took me two minutes to try and reproduce it with a structure ie `<cfset numRes = { dsn1=queryNew(""), dsn2=queryNew(""), ...}>` but ... the cfloop above worked fine, so without more specific info - unfortunately I am out of ideas.

Comment: @Leigh That's pretty much what it is, just some <cfquery> and <cfreturn> on the name property of cfquery.

Comment: @Janet I recommend starting from scratch. Whilst troubleshooting, forget the "real world" code and derive a hypothesis of what the problem might be, test it, analyse the outcome. Adjust the hypothesis as needs must to augment the situation until you can either repro the situation using *only* test code, or you will have found your problem along the way. I recommend you read this: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/12/need-help-know-how-to-ask-for-it.html and this: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html